# Are there any equivalents to size_t in C++ in Java?

Tags: java, c++, size-t

So I am VERY new to Java., but I actually really like it so far. I am comfortable in C++ and was trying to convert some of my code to learn more. I am stuck in translating my code at `size_t`. I know there are no unsigned integer types in Java, but could I use `long` instead? Would I just have to watch out for the case of negatives?

Thank for the insight!

Comment: JAVA collections seem to return `int` for their `size` method, [look here for example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), so I'm guessing `int` would be the counterpart for `size_t`.

Comment: It depends. If you want to represent the size of a Java collection, `int` is usually enough. But if you want to represent the size of a huge file in the file system, the max value of `int` is only 2GB and you really need `long`. @triple_r

Comment: @nicky_zs You are right, I thought size_t is just for std "collections" in c++11, but apparently it is for "size of theoretically possible object of any type (including array)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java doesn't have unsigned types. But `long` in Java is 64-bit so it is definitely enough to be a `size_t`.

And, yes, for a bug free system, you can always watch out the unexpected case of negatives.

Comment: `size_t` is often a 64-bit unsigned type, so it won't cover half of the values in that case.

Comment: Yes, the max value of an unsigned 64-bit `size_t` is 18446744073709551615, while `long` have only the half, which is 9223372036854775807. But... is that huge number not enough for most case? @chris

Comment: I sure hope so. There's still always `BigInteger` or whatever it is exactly in Java.

Comment: By your reasoning, `size_t` in C++ is also NOT exactly for it also has a limit. Why C++ doesn't use something like `BigInteger` to represent the size? @chris

Comment: `size_t` is from C. C++ does not (yet, possibly) have a `BigInteger` class. C definitely did not.

Comment: So, you think in C++, sizeof(SomeCollection) and file.size() should return a value of BigInteger? @chris

Comment: No, not really. That would be pretty unnecessary. I just gave one technical reason why it isn't like that.